# Calculate cosine similarity of document relevance

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I have go the normalized TF-IDF for and also the keyword RDD and now want to compute the cosine similarity to find relevance score for the document .

So I tried as

```
    documentRdd = sc.textFile("documents.txt").flatMap(lambda l: re.split(r'[^\w]+',l))
    keyWords = sc.textFile("keywords.txt").flatMap(lambda l: re.split(r'[^\w]+',l))
    normalizer1 = Normalizer()
    hashingTF = HashingTF()
    tf = hashingTF.transform(documentRdd)
    tf.cache()
    idf = IDF().fit(tf)
    tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
    normalizedtfidf=normalizer1.transform(tfidf)
```

Now I wanted to calculate the cosine similarity between the normalizedtfidf and keyWords.So I tried using

```
x = Vectors.dense(normalizedtfidf)
y = Vectors.dense(keywordTF)
print(1 - x.dot(y)/(x.norm(2)*y.norm(2)) , "is the releavance score")
```

But this throw the error as

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Which means I am passing a wrong format .Any help is appreciated .

**Update**

I tried then

```
    x = Vectors.sparse(normalizedtfidf.count(),normalizedtfidf.collect())
    y = Vectors.sparse(keywordTF.count(),keywordTF.collect())
```

but got

> TypeError: Cannot treat type  as a
>   vector

as the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the errors because you are attempting to convert RDD into Vectors forcibly.

You can achieve what you need without doing the conversion by doing the following steps :

1. Join both your RDDs into one RDD. Note that I am assuming you do not have a unique index in both RDDs for joining.

```
# Adding index to both RDDs by row.
rdd1 = normalizedtfidf.zipWithIndex().map(lambda arg : (arg[1], arg[0]))
rdd2 = keywordTF.zipWithIndex().map(lambda arg : (arg[1], arg[0]))

# Join both RDDs.
rdd_joined = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

2. `map` RDD with a function to calculate cosine distance.

```
def cosine_dist(row):
    x = row[1][0]
    y = row[1][1]
    return (1 - x.dot(y)/(x.norm(2)*y.norm(2)))

res = rdd_joined.map(cosine_dist)
```

You can then use your results or run `collect` to see them.

Comment: Well this returns me [1.0, 1.0] for all documents which is not correct I guess

Comment: The code should be correct. Can you post a few data points from your 2 documents, "documents.txt" and "keywords.txt"?

Comment: Just a quick question why does res.collect() returns 2 values as [1.0, 1.0]? Shouldn't the relevance be one number

Comment: `res.collect()` will return one value per row in your data. If you get 2 values, that means you have 2 rows in `normalizedtfidf` and 2 rows in `keywordTF`. The idea is that you are comparing row 1 in `normalizedtfidf` with row 1 in `keywordTF` and so on.

Comment: Should i use keywordTF or keyWords directly